# how to add a class via binding in ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I have a bootstrap button group in my Ember 2.2 app that looks like this:

```
 <div class='btn-group' role='group' aria-label='...'>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xsm active={{aIsActive}}" >A</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xsm active={{bIsActive}}" >B</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xsm active={{cIsActive}}" >C</button>
</div>
```

'aIsActive', 'bIsActive', and 'cIsActive' are defined in the associated controller, and only one will be 'true' at a given time.  The syntax shown above doesn't work.  What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go: [if-helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/templates/conditionals/)

```
<button class="btn {{if aIsActive 'active'}}" >A</button>
```

btw, if you are creating navigation you should do it with link-to helper. It will add active class automatically when route is active.